# Access to superceded system

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu.  It has replaced widows 7.  I was hoping to have access to both systems but I have lost the original and many documents, music, pictures, etc.  Can I get these back?

Comment: Are you certain it has not installed alongside? Some info about your system would help, in particular the output of 'sudo fdisk -l' ; if it has over-written the old system, there are ways of getting much back PROVIDED you don't write too much more to disk. Do you have a large drive you can copy to?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "lost", did you format the partition in which your Win7 docs music and pictures were located?  If not then correct ubuntu behavior is that your old windows "C:" drive in NTFS will have been shrunk to make at least 16 to 20GB of space for new linux partitions and given a linux partitionname such as sda3
When you find that [either listed as sda3 or by its size such as "300GB Partition" then "open" it from the dropdown menu which appears while you mouseover it and rightmousebutton.  There should be your old "C:" drive contents.
Unless you told it not to at the time of installing GRUB bootloader, when you boot your computer you should see a list in white text on a black background of what to boot to.  Top of the list will be the latest linux and lower on the list it should say "Windows 7".

Of course it is possible to blotto the whole Windows 7 legacy os if you told it to do that during formatting and installation.